# Undefined arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been working on a website when I had a javascript problem I made  an empty array and then added the following script.

```
  while(e<=f){
        array[0]=array[0]+x.charAt(e);
        e++;
        console.log(array[0]);
    }
```

I get the same value that I want but the word "undefined" with it

Comment: what are the values of the variables?

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: You have to add more information and example code for it to make sense to anyone

Answer (score 3):

If `array` is initially empty, then `array[0]` is initially undefined.  So this operation:

```
array[0]+x.charAt(e)
```

will produce "undefined" concatenated with some value.

You can conditionally use an empty string when `array[0]` is `undefined`, for example:

```
(array[0] || '') + x.charAt(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you made the array like that

```
new Array(100)
```

then a[1] will return you undefined because this is an array of 'empty' - try to make your array like this

```
const a = Array.from({length: 100}, (item, index)=> index)
```

with the map function as the second argument